# Errors about apt-secure when trying to run system update on 16.10

Tags: apt, 16.10

While updating getting error when running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The error:

```
The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? is it 16.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.10 is not supported any more (since July 2017), hence there are no information about packages available anymore (as indicated by the `does no longer have a Release file` message.

Your choices are to downgrade to 16.04 or upgrade to 17.10

Comment: thanx i install ubuntu 17.10